# Can't access property from JSON file, why?

Tags: json, typescript

Here's the JSON:

```
data = {
    "company_name": "חברה לדוגמה",
    "audit_period_begin": "01/01/2021",
    "audit_period_end": "31/12/2021",
    "reports": [
        {
            "type": {
                "he": "מאזן",
                "en": "Balance Sheets"
            },
            "fin_statement": "BS",
            "sections": [
                {
                    "section_name": {
                        "he": "נכסים שוטפים",
                        "en": "Current Assets"
                    },
                    "totals": {
                        "2020": {
                            "final_total_local": 100000,
                            "final_total_foreign": 0
                        },
                        "2021": {
                            "final_total_local": 110000,
                            "final_total_foreign": 0
                        }
                    },
                    "subsections": [
                        {......(the rest is irrelevant)
```

and I'm trying to call:

```
data.reports[0].sections[0]['totals']
```

but I get an error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"totals"' can't be used to index type
```

and can't read the property, why?

Comment: 1. That's **not** JSON, just an object literal. 2. Of type... what? What's the inferred or explicit type you're trying to access?

Comment: `data.reports[0].sections[0].totals`

Answer (score 1):

After you acquire `data.reports[0].sections[0].totals` probably successfully you are accessing it as if it was an array, whereas it's an object. try `data.reports[0].sections[0]['totals']["2020"]` instead of `data.reports[0].sections[0]['totals'][2020]`. This is just a guess as you didn't provide enough code.